# How to solve the conflict caused by shaded without changing the package name？

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, apache-flink

My project has two dependencies
flink-kubetnets and flink-kubernrts-operator, Let's call him A, B
The A shaded the kubernets-client into itself and not change package name, and B also dependend  kubernets-client with different version.
So they conflict, how to solve it?

I tried packing again with shaded, but no, It seems that this situation can no longer be solved with shaded.
Because both A and B call kubernets-client, shaded cannot change their internal codes

Comment: You could try using a [dependency exclusion](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) to exclude one version of the dependency.  But if the two intermediate dependencies (`flink-kubetnets` and `flink-kubernrts-operator`) **really** need those specific versions of `kubernets-client`, you need to look for and use alternate (compatible) versions of **them**.

Comment: thx. So there really is no way to coexist ?

Comment: Technically, they can.  But you would need to load the relevant parts of `fklink-kubetnets` and `flink-kubernrts-operator` in separate classloaders so that they can load the two versions of `kubernets-client`.  That's complicated, and it may well be impractical.  And you are adding a whole lot of *technical debt* to your project.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.